# Getting segmentation error while passing input through runtime

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
int main(int argc, char* argv) {

    struct student_record_node *head;
    char *filename = argv[1];
    printf("%s",filename);
    parseFile(filename,&head);
    return (0); 
}

struct student_record_node* student_record_allocate() 
{
    struct student_record_node *newNode;
    newNode =  malloc(sizeof (struct student_record_node));
    return newNode;
}

void parseFile(char *filename, struct student_record_node**head) 
{
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    char fname[21], flast[21];
    int id,age;
    int ret;

    /*creates a POINTER to "filename"*/
    fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (fp== NULL) {
        printf("No such file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s",fp->_tmpfname);

    while (fp) {
        struct student_record_node *new_student;
        new_student = student_record_allocate();
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d %d",new_student->record_->first_name_ , new_student->record_->last_name_,new_student->record_->student_id_, new_studen    t->record_->student_age_);
        new_student->next_ = NULL;
        if (*head == NULL)
            *head=new_student;
        else {
            struct student_record_node *temp = *head;
            while (temp->next_ != NULL) {
                temp = temp->next_;
            }
            temp->next_=new_student;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is c++

Comment: yes but any help will be apprecitaed for logic.

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d %d", ...` is wrong. 1)  `new_student->record_` isn't  initialize (don't point to record object). 2) `new_student->record_->student_id_` --> `&new_student->record_->student_id_`

Comment: `while (fp) {` : `fp` is always true.

Comment: i did that and i was getting the same error.

Comment: `new_student_allocate()` allocates memory for `new_student`, but it doesn't allocate any memory for `new_student->record_`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Seeing some problem in your code :-

1. Problem in memory allocation. In your case you didn't typecast void* into struct student_record_node. As malloc returns void*
2. why are you using fp in while loop? if you successfully open the file, you will get valid pointer (fp) point to your file and you will be in infinite loop.
3. As you did not post you structure declaration, i can say only if first_name_ and last_name_ is not defined as arrey then you need to allocate memory to these variables.